# Haskell function with no input arguments

Tags: haskell

How can I define a function that takes *no* arguments?

```hs
data Address
   = Address
   {
       city :: String,
       street :: String
   }
   deriving ( Show )

-- mkIncompleteAddress :: () -> Address
-- mkIncompleteAddress = Address "NYC" "<TBD>"

mkIncompleteAddress :: Address
mkIncompleteAddress = Address "NYC" "<TBD>"
```

The closest I can get is a constant (?) global variable (?)
When I remove the comments I get:

```
Main.hs:10:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘() -> Address’
                  with actual type ‘Address’
    • Possible cause: ‘Address’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: Address "NYC" "<TBD>"
      In an equation for ‘mkIncompleteAddress’:
          mkIncompleteAddress = Address "NYC" "<TBD>"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "function that takes no arguments", if not what you have here? And, once you've said what you mean, why do you want that?

Comment: @DanielWagner I have Addresses that are either partial or complete. At some later phase, the partial addresses will be completed. I thought I'd "allocate" a partial address and "complete" it later. I guess my thinking was "too-cpp-like" as I now see that all these "allocated address" are essentially just a *single*, *constant* address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkIncompleteAddress :: Address` *is* a function which takes no arguments. In Haskell, that’s more or less the same thing as a global constant, since non-`IO` functions don’t have side-effects and values are lazily evaluated.

On the other hand, it’s still entirely possible to write a function `mkIncompleteAddress :: () -> Address`, like so:

```
mkIncompleteAddress :: () -> Address
mkIncompleteAddress x = Address "NYC" "<TBD>"
```

Or, you can be really explicit and pattern-match on the input:

```
mkIncompleteAddress :: () -> Address
mkIncompleteAddress () = Address "NYC" "<TBD>"
```

Syntactically, this looks a bit like a function with no arguments, but it isn’t: it’s a function which requires one argument, where this argument happens to have `()` as its only value.

---

However, I would invite you to reconsider your approach here. `Address "NYC" "<TBD>"` is, quite obviously, invalid as an address, and using such values in your program just makes mistakes easier to make. I’d recommend doing something like this instead:

```
mkIncompleteAddress :: String -> Address
mkIncompleteAddress street = Address "NYC" street
```

Or even simpler, taking advantage of currying:

```
mkIncompleteAddress :: String -> Address
mkIncompleteAddress = Address "NYC"
```

Comment: To expand on your first point: precisely speaking, Haskell functions are types that go `… -> …`, and they all take exactly 1 parameter; yet in practice we also often refer to a function as taking 2 or more parameters, as if it weren’t curried. So, even though it is a common misconception that a value is a 0-parameter function, I don’t think there’s really any harm in it either, as an illustration to help learn the language.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll consider that idea. The only thing that bothers me is that I have some *complete* addresses and some *partial* addresses being handled by the same functions - so using your suggestion, these 2 addresses kinds will have *different* types, right?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom If you genuinely do need to handle partial addresses so often, I’d suggest reflecting that directly in the type: something like `data Address = Address { city :: String, street :: Maybe String }`, perhaps.